# jQuery How to optimize menu with active thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

Here is how it looks like:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/armando-perez/index.html#

Here is the jQuery, which handles the appropriate thumbnails activation according to the clicked (activated) horizontal menu element.

```
var main = function() {
  $('.nav li').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('class');

    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if (category === 'nav-consumer') {
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
      $('.consumer').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-mobile') {
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
      $('.mobile').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-commerce') {
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
      $('.commerce').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-enterprise') {
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
      $('.enterprise').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-all') {
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
    }

  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

As you can see, this is the code from one of the codecademy's jquery final projects. It is certainly working, but the problem is, we have a lot of simple and repeating code, which is unnecessary. Do you have any idea how to efficiently optimize it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know that i am a newbie :) The only thing i have managed to improve is the unjustified repetition of $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');

```
var main = function() {
  $('.nav li').click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('class');

    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');

    if (category === 'nav-consumer') {
      $('.consumer').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-mobile') {
      $('.mobile').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-commerce') {
      $('.commerce').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-enterprise') {
      $('.enterprise').addClass('selected');
    }

    else if (category === 'nav-all') {
    }

  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```